# How do you mix raw SQL with ORM APIs when you use django.db?

Tags: python, sql, orm, django-models

ORM tools are great when the queries we need are simple `select` or `insert` clauses.

But sometimes we may have to fall back to use raw SQL queries, because we may need to make queries so complex that simply using the ORM API can not give us an efficient and effective solution.

What do you do to deal with the difference between objects returned from *raw queries* and *orm queries*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally strive to design my models so I don't have to deffer to writing raw SQL queries, or fallback to mixing in the [`ContentTypes`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) framework for complex relationships, so I have no experience on the topic.

The documentation covers the topic of the APIs for [performing raw SQL queries](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/). You can either use the `Manager.raw()` on your models (`MyModel.objects.raw()`), for queries where you can map columns back to actual model fields, or user `cursor` to query raw rows on your database connection.

If your going to use `Manager.raw()`, you'll work with the `RawQuerySet` instead of the usual `QuerySet`. For all things concerned, when working with result objects the two emulate containers identically, but the `QuerySet` is a more feature-packed monad.

I can imagine that performing raw SQL queries in Django would be more rewarding than working with a framework with no ORM support—Django can manage your database schema and provide you with a database connection and you'll only have to manually create queries and position query arguments. The resulting rows can be accessed as lists or dictionaries, both of which make it suitable for displaying in templates or performing additional lifting.

Comment: Yes, `Manager.raw()` helps a lot when performing raw SQL queries. I wonder if SQLAlchemy has somethings similar.

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy allows a fair bit of complexity in formulating [queries](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/sqlexpression.html) so you can usually get away without raw sql.  If you do need to dip down to raw sql, you can use `connection.execute`.  But there are helpers like the `text` and `select` [functions](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/sqlexpression.html#sqlexpression-text) to make this easier when programming.  As far as dealing with the returned objects, you get a list of tuples which are simple to deal with in a pythonic way.

In general, if you need to treat rows (list of tuples, etc) as what your ORM returns, one approach would be to write an adapter class which mimics a queryset interface.  This could be initialized with the "schema" of the returned tuples, and then iterate and return objects with properties instead of tuples.  I haven't really needed this, but I can see how it might be useful if, for example, you have a framework which relies on querysets being passed around.

Comment: But tuple is not object and when mixed with object returned by the ORM API, we have to design at least two sets of operations to deal with them differently, is it so?

Comment: OK, I think I missed the point of your question earlier, please see the update.  But the short answer is, yes.  An adapter would be the best way to deal with this issue of mismatching interfaces (tuples or whatever versus querysets or other objects).